# accessing class name by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with 3 classes like:

```
   <div class = "a b c"> .. </div>
```

Now i want to access only `class b` by .attr(), is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with class b?

Comment: what do you want to do to `b`? is `b` known in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var classB = $('#element_id').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean by "access".  You can check to see if an element has a class:

```
if ($(elem).hasClass("b")) { ... }
```

or

```
if ($(elem).is(".b")) { ... }
```

You can look for your element by that class with a simple selector:

```
var with_class_b = $('.b');
```

It's generally a good idea to not mess with the "className" property (not attribute) yourself if you're using jQuery. You *can*, of course, but there's really no point.